# Как в файле ресурсов String задать пробелы вначале строки

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.Возникла необходимость в файле ресурсов "String" добавить строку с несколькими пробелами вначале.Но я что то подзабыл какими символами пробелы кодируются, чтобы они были видны.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно заключить строку в кавычки "  your string", или добавить /t

Answer (score 0):

Привет.

Добавь следующий код: & #032; 
Еще можно \u 0020 или & #160;
*без пробелов между & и #